# App in app purchase: Is there any delegate method if there is no product to restore?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, product, restore

I have one app provide "restore" button for user to restore previous purchased product.

But if the user has not purchased any product before, when he clicks the 'restore' button

```
([[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];)
```

the program will hang on waiting for response from apple. Neither:

```
(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

nor

```
(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)
```

error got called.

Is there any recommended way to handle this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0):

There must be an error if net or Apple server is down. Check it on physical device. Moreover, if you want to check if there is any product or not, you can check as follows;

```
- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
if([queue.transactions count]>0){
    NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);
} 
else {
    NSLog(@"No Product to restore"); 
}
```